# WPF SharedSize complex layout

Tags: c#, wpf, markup

**What I need:**

A grid with several rows and colums, with checkbox in each cell:

```
      | header | header | ... | AddColBtn
------|--------|--------|-----|------
legend| check  | check  | ... |
------|--------|--------|-----|
 ...  |  ...   |  ...   |     |
```

**What I have:**

XAML markup is this:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{someBinding}" x:Name="HeadersControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <somens:AddColButton Grid.Column="2"/>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="DataControl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{anotherBinding}"/>                        
</Grid>
```

Item templates for HeadersControl and DataControl are set from code-behind.

Template for HeadersControl is like this:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Header"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <somens:Header/>
</Grid>
```

And a template for DataControl is like this:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Legend"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <somens:Legend/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Header"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox/>
                </Grid>
            <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I had two troubles: first is that headers were not evenly distributed along the top-side of the grid, which I solved by setting HeadersControl.ItemsPanel to UniformGrid. Then is started aligning checkboxws with legend, which is the second trouble. I added shared size groups, and that is where everything fell apart. Wherever I put `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` in templates for ItemControls it doesn't seem to work and I get this:[image]

Theese circles must be directly under headers. Could somebody tell me please what am I missing?

**Update:**

After leaving `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` only on main grid, i got this:

[image]

This makes me completely confused, could that be possibly an issue with my usercontrol, that representates the header?

Comment: `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` seems to work (partially) because legend column is sized equally in header and in rows. But maybe a simpler solution is to use `<UniformGrid Rows="1"/>` panel in DataControl template?

Comment: @ASh for some reason it gives the same result as in first picture